# Раскрыть аккордеон меню

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  $('.j-accordion-menu a').each(function() {

    var location = window.location.href;

    var link = this.href;

    if (location == link) {

        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');

        $(this).parents('.j-accordion-menu li').addClass('open').children('ul').show();

        $(this).parents('.j-accordion-menu ul').show();

    }

});
```

Все работает, добавляет open для родителя и active для активного. Но, если перейти внутрь, например /category/type/good - уже type не определяется, соответственно не добавляется ни актив ни опен. Как  var location = window.location.href; реализовать иначе?

/dress/vechernie-platya/
Dress главный родитель, vechernie-platya - меньший родитель. Если перейти в пункт vechernie-platya - то родитель dress получит open, а vechernie-platya - active.
Но, если внутри vechernie-platya перейти непосредственно в товар
/dress/vechernie-platya/plate-v-pol
То dress не получит open, а vechernie-platya active.

Comment: Думаю не достаточно хорошо объяснили проблему.

Comment: не совсем понятно, что здесь является this.href, добавьте html и сделайте вопрос в виде снипета

Comment: Проблему решил так       if (window.location.href.indexOf(link) > -1) . Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Более современное решение:

```
window.location.href.includes(link);
```